# Same android cmake git project compiles well on one Ubuntu machine but does not compile on another Ubuntu machine even the entire project is the same

Tags: android, c++, ubuntu, compilation, cmake

I'm developing an android cmake project that compiles succesfully on my 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 machine at work (I will call it WorkMachine). When I want to compile it at home, I installed a 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine (I will call it HomeMachine), I git cloned the project on it, and when I start the compilation, it will block with an error.

```
CMAKE_CFLAGS are: 
CMAKE_CXXFLAGS are: 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/raa/Dropbox/Demo/android_build
[  0%] Built target bitstream
[  0%] Built target distrat
[  1%] Built target fisher
[  1%] Built target gtest
[  7%] Built target jpeg-8c
[  7%] Built target map
[  8%] Built target resampler
[  9%] Built target timer
[ 92%] Built target fftw3f-3
[ 96%] Built target vlfeat
[ 96%] Built target extract_shared
[ 97%] Built target shared
[ 97%] Built target cssc_train
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/extract
/home/raa/Dropbox/Demo/libraries/fftw-3.3.3/api/configure.c:28: error: undefined reference to 'fftwf_dft_conf_standard'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/extract] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/extract.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here I am reporting gcc version (the same on both computers)

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

But how is that possible?
It seems the problem is not due to some cmake cache or similar chaches, because if I git clone the project on another directory on the WorkMachine, the code compiles well too.
What can I check in order to resolve the problem? If you need additional details, please ask me.

Thank you for your time.

Riccardo

Comment: It seems like there is some dependencies missing. Some .h file with the declaration of 'fftwf_dft_conf_standard' that you may have in your WorkMachine that is not installed in your HomeMachine.

Comment: I checked with 'nm' if that specific symbol (fftwf_dft_conf_standard) is present in the library fftw3f-3.a (builded succesfully as you can see in my previous post) BUT in HomeMachine there is no evidence of that symbol, while in WorkMachine the symbol is correctly placed. It seems that the same project is linked differently in two different machines! There is a way to find if cmake_link_script is working well while creating my fftw3f-3.a library?

Comment: You can run `make VERBOSE=1` to see most of the commands run by make.

Comment: whoa! Solved! It was really a weird behaviour from cmake: I had three files conf.c that must be merged into a static library. When cmake run the AR program to create the library, it executed a command that was like:

     ar cr dir1/source1.c dir1/source2.c ... dft/conf.c rdft/conf.c
     ar r  reodft/conf.c dir2/source3.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whoa! Solved! It was really a weird behaviour from cmake: I had three files conf.c that must be merged into a static library. When cmake run the AR program to create the library, it executed a command that was like:

```
ar cr dir1/source1.c dir1/source2.c ... dft/conf.c rdft/conf.c 
ar r reodft/conf.c dir2/source3.c
```

so, maybe due to the huge number of object files that were to be linked, cmake splitted ar commands in two command, BUT second command overwrited one of the two file conf.c that were added with the first command, so symbols defined with the first ar command were lost! This is clearly a bug in ar because even if the source file is the same, maybe the content may vary, thus symbols are not to be deleted. Thanks to all! Your suggestions brought me to the right solution!

Answer (score 1):

the solution to Riccardos problem is to change the commandline parameter of `ar` from r to q (see man page for difference, basically q does not check for duplicats)

do this via

```
SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_APPEND "<CMAKE_AR> q  <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
```

you probably want to check if `CMAKE_AR` is "ar" (might be different on other systems)